# Is there a trick using the Components object by which I can $Ref a frequently used Description object?

Tags: openapi

I find myself repeating a description again and again within a requestbody > content.  I looked for a DRY technique in the OpenAPI v3 Specification where I might use a $Ref in order to simplify things. Nothing jumped out at me.  So I thought I would ask the experts here if they know a way.

Answer (score 1):

Is it purely the description which repeats, or a sub-section of your requestBody content schema? If the former, you can simply break down your schema into sub-schemas and `$ref` them. If the latter...

As `description` is a string property not an object, it cannot be replaced by a `$ref`, but you can use the `allOf` schema keyword to combine schemas:

```
allOf:
  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/myDescription'
  - ... # other schema properties
```

and in your `components/schemas`:

```
myDescription:
  description: 'Re-usable description here'
```